# How to copy a folder via cmd?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to make a .bat file that when opened will copy a folder and all it contains into another folder on another partition. Here is exactly what I am trying to do:

Copy `C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\Документи` and all it contains to `D:\Backup`. I have tried with many [`xcopy`](http://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html) commands but without result. Thanks.

I launched the command prompt with `/k` and saw this

[image: pic]

which made me think there is a problem with the font. I installed new font that should fix this (`YGP_NT`) but I am having the same problem (yes, I changed it from the cmd Properties, edited the TrueTypeFont with regedit and restarted the PC). I can write in cyrillic in the cmd if that can help.

Comment: If you've "tried with many xcopy commands", certainly you should be able to include some of them in your post. Please [edit] to do so, and explain how they don't work as you'd expect.

Comment: change the character set, not the font (although you should change to a true type font for better Unicode support and rendering). Use `chcp <codepage>` with your Russian codepage, or [`chcp 65001`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388490/995714) for changing to UTF-8

Answer (score 55):

```
xcopy "%userprofile%\Desktop\Документи" "D:\Backup\" /s/h/e/k/f/c
```

should work, assuming that your language setting allows Cyrillic (or you use Unicode fonts in the console).

For reference about the arguments: http://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html

Comment: +1 As you are using a non-default character set then you may have issues with the characters and need to use the `CP` command to change the code page before executing the xcopy command.  You may get a `path not found` error otherwise.  I added some switches to the xcopy command, plus quotes and slash

Comment: This didn't work, the cmd just flashes and the Backup folder is still empty. I checked the paths and all seems fine.

Comment: Trying with "/s/h/e/k/f/c" on command prompt, I was asked if it is a file or directory I wanted to copy. Try with the parameters /E /C /I /Y.

Comment: I would remove /c

Answer (score 27):

```
xcopy  e:\source_folder f:\destination_folder /e /i /h
```

The /h is just in case there are hidden files. The /i creates a destination folder if there are muliple source files.

Answer (score 12):

```
xcopy  "C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\Документи" "D:\Backup" /s /e /y /i
```

Probably the problem is the space.Try with quotes.